# Getting the ID of a parent DOM element that fires an event, with vainilla JS

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to find out if it is possible to capture the ID of an HTML element (a DIV) , parent of other elements (span, img...), through the object generated by the addEventListener event.

More specifically, what I am trying is that regardless of where I click, the text above would be replaced by "IdDiv", which is the ID assigned to the DIV element in which the span and the img are nested.

What I am getting right now is the ID of the element in which I am actually clicking.

I hope my code helps as an example of what I am trying to say

Pd:looking for vanilla JS solutions, since it is what I am starting with.

```js
const myListOfElements = [
    {
     id: 1,
     name: "Text 1",
     img: "https://placehold.it/300?text=Elemento%201"
    },
    {
     id: 2,
     name: "Text 2",
     img: "https://placehold.it/300?text=Elemento%202"
    },
    {
     id: 3,
     name: "Text 3",
     img: "https://placehold.it/300?text=Elemento%203"
    }
   ];
   
   const createElements = (elementsArray) => {
     const container = document.querySelector('#container');
     
     elementsArray.forEach(({id, name, img}) => {
        const element = document.createElement('div');
        element.setAttribute('id', 'idDiv')
        
        // creating Span and append it to parent
        const elementSpan = document.createElement('span');
        elementSpan.setAttribute('id', 'idSpan')
        elementSpan.innerText = name;
        element.appendChild(elementSpan);
        
        // creating IMG element and append it to parent
        const elementImg = document.createElement('img');
        elementImg.setAttribute('src', img);
        elementImg.setAttribute('alt', name);
        elementImg.setAttribute('id', 'idImg');
        element.appendChild(elementImg);
        
        // adding eventListenet
        element.addEventListener('click', () => {
          const targetElement = document.querySelector('#oneText');
          targetElement.innerText = event.target.id;
          console.log(event.target.id);
        });
        
        // add element to container
        container.appendChild(element);
     }) 
   }
   
   createElements(myListOfElements);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


<span id="oneText">THIS TEXT MUST CHANGE</span>
<div id="container">
</div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="prueba.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you want id of parent element or child element?

Comment: of parent element.

Trying to get "IdDiv" which is the Id from the DIV element, parent of the Span and Img elements

Answer (score 0):

with the parentNode it will give the id of the element clicked parent

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <ul id="myUl">
        <li id="myLi">List Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

var li = document.getElementById('myLi');
li.addEventListener('click',function(e){
   console.log(e.target.parentNode.id);
});
```

Comment: THanks Naveen, but not what i try

Given your code, what I try is: to assign the click event to the DIV, so when I click in any element inside of it (div, ul, li), i get the ID from the DIV (id="oneDiv") :

`code`

`<div id="oneDiv" class="myDiv"> div item
        <ul id="myUl"> ul item
            <li id="myLi">List Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
var li = document.getElementById('oneDiv');
    li.addEventListener('click',function(e){
       console.log(e.target.parentNode.id);
    }); `

But with this, i get differents IDs depending where I click.

Comment: sorry for the bad comment format ..do not allow me to change it any more